# TYPO3- How to set up notification-emails

Tags: typo3

I want to configure my Typo-3 instance such that emails are automatically sent to the admin's email address whenever:

- Someone tries to login with incorrect login-information
- Someone logs in successfully

I also want to receive emails about the state of my website regularly. How/where can I set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really want to get an email every time someone tries to log in?
I'd rather go for a custom extension that reads `sys_log` table and then use a scheduler task to send you a report on a regular basis.

Nevertheless, in the install wide options in the settings module you can configure `[BE][warning_mode]` to send an email upon backend login. But I'm not sure if attempts are also covered.

By the way: each user can configure their personal account to send an email notification on every login. Maybe that's an alternative to a global notification system.

Regarding the website state: TYPO3 ships with a reports module. This module provides a "System Status Update" scheduler task to get those reports via mail regularly.